# SemrushBot cannot be stopped

Tags: web-scraping, bots, web-crawler, robots.txt

In the last few days I was monitoring my website logs and saw a bot that is scanning me a lot.
The interval of scanning is very frequently, once of every 5-10 seconds. I was trying to block the bot by write the next code into **robots.txt**, but after 1 or 2 hours nothing happened, the bot is continuing to scan.

What can I do to stop the bot? Is it a sign that someone is trying to do something harmful to my website?

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /

User-agent: SemrushBot
Disallow: /
```

*Log example*

```
185.191.171.11 - - [07/Nov/2022:11:38:59 +0200] "GET /example_store.php?id_class=123&id_product=1234&watch=20670906 HTTP/1.1" 500 5225 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SemrushBot/7~bl; +http://www.semrush.com/bot.html)"
```

Comment: It can take some time. You can also block the IP.

Comment: It could be a bot impersonating Semrush. Here is your chance to fight a rogue bot.

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus can you give me more details please. How I can identify the real bot?

Comment: It might take 2 weeks for the bot to notice the change in your robots.txt and obey it.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask similar questions there instead.

Answer (score 0):

Bots don't re-fetch `robots.txt` every time they make a call. They cache the file for some amount of time, typically 24 hours. [Their documentation](https://www.semrush.com/bot/) doesn't say how long they cache it, but I would expect that you would have to wait more than a couple hours to see changes in bot behavior.

It is also possible that this is some rogue bot that is impersonating a known crawler.  If that is the case, it is unlikely to obey `robots.txt` at all.

If you want more immediate results you can block the bot by IP address or by user agent on your firewall, your CDN, your load balancer, or your server.  For example, if your site is using Apache server, you can add a line to your `.htaccess` to block the bot.  See [How to block a specific website browser agent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50288374/how-to-block-a-specific-website-browser-agent)

Comment: I can't block the bot by IP, because everytime it's a different one: 185.191.171.4 // 185.191.171.42 // 185.191.171.11 // 185.191.171.38 // 185.191.171.33 and so on... All this connections are in just one minute.